# Can html 5 video and its captions be served from a CDN?

Tags: html, html5-video, cors, video.js, closed-captions

I was wondering if its possible to serve a video  and its subtitle from a CDN such as AWS Cloudfront with HTML5 VIDEO?

This is my html5 video code : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akds86um/)

```
<video   controls    preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="https://s3.amazonaws.com/testpipeoutput/myjunittesting/vlcsnap-2015-07-02-13h39m38s227.png"
                   >
                <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/testpipeoutput/myjunittesting/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <track kind="captions" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/testpipeoutput/myjunittesting/captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English">
            </video>
```

In this case I am attempting to serve both the video and it captions file from my AWS Bucket and I get this exception

**(index):1 Text track from origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.**

Please note that I have CORS enabled for my S3 bucket.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: fixed typo and add cors tag

Comment: What is the CORS configuration you have set on your bucket?

Comment: My bucket CORS configuration is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to your video tag:

https://jsfiddle.net/akds86um/3/